# Mains voltage higher with load than without

Tags: voltage, relay, mains

I have a power socket wattmeter which measures 238 Vac (I'm in Europe, nominal voltage is 230 Vac). When I connect a relay before the wattmeter, it measures a *higher voltage*: 261 Vac. What's causing this?

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8NeW.jpg)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTSy7.jpg)

[image: 3]

Comment: Some capacitance in your wattmeter may be causing some ringing.

Comment: I agree. Plug some sort of basic resistive load like an incandescent light or small heater, into the meter so you're not measuring open-circuit.